# how to display date only in datepicker from database using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker

```
app.controller('getUser', function ($scope, $http, $cookieStore) {

$http.get('http://localhost:8080/myapp/user/'.concat($scope.getUserId) + '?access_token=' + $cookieStore.get("access_token")).
        then(function (response) {
            $scope.users = response.data;
        });});

    Table name: user{ id  | userDate | 1 |  2016-11-28 05:30:00.0}

<div ng-controller="getUser">
<label class="control-label">Date</label>
<input type="date"  class="form-control" ng-model="users.userDate" ng-value="{{users.userDate"}}">
</div>
```

Its not displaying date in date picker. Could you give me solution.
Thanks

Comment: I presume *users* contains actually one user. So... what do you need for `ng-value="{{users.userDate"}}"` when you have already a `ng-model="users.userDate"`?

Comment: it would appear you have an extra `"` `ng-value="{{users.userDate"}}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add this to your html

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="users.userdate">
```

As the above line is expecting date object which you are not passing as you are passing date as a string.

and add this line to your script after you fetch your data.

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/myapp/user/'.concat($scope.getUserId) + '?access_token=' + $cookieStore.get("access_token")).
    then(function (response) {
        $scope.users = response.data;
        $scope.users.userdate = new Date($scope.users.userdate); // converting into date object which will display date in correct form in your html
    });});
```

If you don't want to add the above script then you can make your input tag `type="text"` which will work fine but it will not popup datepicker.

Comment: you also have an extra attribute which is not at all needed `ng-value="{{users.userDate}}"`

Answer (score 0):

Refer [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.value)

You need to provide the `value` to `<input type='date'>` in the correct acceptable format (`YYYY-MM-DD`) for it be shown correctly in the HTML5 date input.

You should be able to use filters to format date (in `yyyy-MM-dd` format) or do it in the controller itself before rendering it in the html template.

```
<input type="date"  class="form-control" ng-model="users.userDate" ng-value="{{users.userDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

small change required

```
 <input type="date"  class="form-control" ng-model="userdate" >
```

controller

```
 $scope.userdate= new Date(users.userDate);
```